# Present UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I know this is extremely silly.

I have a view controller that scans a QR code. I create it in the `AppDelegate` (`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`), and I also set my `AppDelegate` as a delegate for the the view controller which will call a method when he finishes scanning the code. In that method, that I have implemented in the `AppDelegate` I want to present a `UINavigationController`. The problem is that it is not presenting my navigation controller. This is my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    reader=[ZBarReaderViewController new];
    reader.readerDelegate=self;
    reader.supportedOrientationsMask=ZBarOrientationMaskAll;
    ZBarImageScanner *scanner=reader.scanner;
    [scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_I25 config:ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to:0]; 


   [self.window addSubview:reader.view];
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   return YES;
}

-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    RootViewController *rootViewController=[[RootViewController alloc] init ];  //create root view controller

    UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];  // create and init navigation controller with viewController
    [navigationController setValue:[[GradientBar alloc] init] forKey:@"navigationBar"];

    rootViewController.title=@"mTLU";
    [reader presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:NO];

}
```

Comment: Can we see the implementation of `[ZBarReaderViewController new]`?

Comment: It is a library I have downloaded from the Internet. They have an example project but they are using a root controller to present the reader and then the same root controller is also the delegate. In my case, I want this ZBarViewController to be the root controller, and after it finishes scanning I want to present a new view controller.

Comment: Seems like you forgot to set `self.window.rootViewController` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to set `self.window.rootViewController` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Try:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   // Override point for customization after application launch.
   self.reader=[ZBarReaderViewController new];
   self.reader.readerDelegate=self;
   self.reader.supportedOrientationsMask=ZBarOrientationMaskAll;
   ZBarImageScanner *scanner=reader.scanner;
   [scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_I25 config:ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to:0]; 

   self.window.rootViewController = self.reader;

   [self.window addSubview:reader.view];
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   return YES;
}
```

This code assumes `reader` is `property` of `AppDelegate`. If it's *only* `iVar` you should ommit `self.` (or consider making it a `property`).

Comment: I have added this     [reader presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: The problem was that in the navigation controller that I was presenting I was connecting to a server that was down, so my app was freezing. Thank you for your time.

Comment: In your code i can't see setting of the `self.window.rootViewController`. It's also not clear which `viewController` you want to be the `rootViewController`. If it's the one you're creating in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` you should create it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and set it as a root. Then in it's `didAppear` you present your `ZBarReaderViewController`...